# How to check if user has a specific role from a specific server then give them a badge in an embed

Tags: discord.js

So I have an economy system in my bot and I want staff members, beta testers, etc in my support server to get this special badge on their profile(embed) command!

So far this is my idea:

```js
let badge = '';

if(message.member.roles.has(<role>.id)) badge = "badge here"
```

I am using discord.js v11.5.1

Comment: You might want to add some more explanation of what you are trying to do.  It wasn't obvious that this was discord related until I saw the tag on it. You will get more answers if you ask questions that show what you have tried and how it has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've created the image of the badge, just use the [`.setThumbnail()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail) method to point to the image or a link of that image so that you can show the badge on their embed.

```js
const member = client.guilds.get(GUILD_ID).members.get(message.author.id);
if (member.roles.has(role)) embed.setThumbnail('link_to_badge_img')
```

If however you'd rather just have a list of badges in the embed's description then you can just list them like so:

```js
const member = client.guilds.get(GUILD_ID).members.get(message.author.id);
if (member.roles.has(role)) embed.setDescription('BadgeTitle')
```

Or in case the user has multiple badges you can create an array of `badges` and push the badges they have to it before finally adding it to the embed description like so:

```js
const member = client.guilds.get(GUILD_ID).members.get(message.author.id);
if (member.roles.has(role)) badges.push('BadgeTitle') //Do this for each badge

if (badges.length) embed.setDescription(`**Badges**\n${badges.join('\n')}`)
```

Comment: Ok that looks good but I want to put it in my .setDescription()

Comment: I edited my answer with 2 new solutions to your issue

Comment: ```let badges = '';

if(message.member.roles.has('Head Developer'.id)) badges.push('<:botdev:700525418775576606>')
  
if(badges.length) profile.setDescription(`**Your Badges**\n${badges.join('\n')}`)```



This didn't seem to work! Just testing with one badge.

Comment: That's not how you check if a member has a role, you'd have to do: `const headDevRole = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === 'Head Developer')` then you can use that in your if statement like so: `if (message.member.roles.has(headDevRole)`

Comment: How would I make this global? So wherever they run the command they can still see their badge as long as they have the role in my server?

Comment: Ok sorry for the message but this didn't work

```let badges = ['']

const member = client.guilds.get('658824686997733399').members.get(message.author.id);
  
if(member.roles.has(headDevRole)) badges.push('<:botdev:701230801072816209>') 

if(badges.length) profile.setDescription(`**Your Badges:** ${badges.join('')}`)```

When I tried it, it didn't show any badges only 'Your Badges'.

Comment: change `let badges = [' ']`to `let badges = []` and you have to console log things like `member` and `member.roles.has(headDevRole)` to understand if they're working and how they're working